# Ошибка при поиске веб-драйвера

Tags: python, selenium

Я пишу программу с помощью Selenium, но веб-драйвер не находится. Я добавила путь к нему в переменную path, пробовала указывать в самом коде путь до драйвера, но все равно выводится ошибка.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: После установки переменных среды, иногда требуется перезагрузить компьютер

Comment: @DanilApsadikov Не требуется.

Comment: Значит указываете, неправильный путь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно указать путь явно, в коде. Не обязательно добавлять в PATH. Для примера:

```
executable_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'chromedriver', 'chromedriver')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(log_path=os.devnull, executable_path=executable_path))
```

Это для Linux. То есть, здесь хромдрайвер в папке chromedriver, в директории со скриптом.

Ну или то же самое, но для Windows:

```
executable_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'chromedriver', 'chromedriver.exe')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(log_path=os.devnull, executable_path=executable_path))
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло